# ¿Qué significa "pata de perro"?

Tags: modismos, méxico

Hoy una amiga me dijo "Soy pata de perro".

Yo entiendo las palabras literalmente, pero ¿qué significa esa expresión?

Comment: Sí, la "pata" es la pierna de los animales.

Comment: En Chile decimos _patiperro_. La expresión "pata de perro" acá no existe.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Significa que le gusta andar por la calle (y, por extensión, se podría también aplicar con el sentido de que le gusta viajar, no quedarse mucho tiempo en un mismo lugar).

El DRAE, en su [entrada para pata](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?id=8mOkTxaKFDXX27dspuUV#pata_de_perro.), nos dice

> ~ de perro.
>
> 1. com. coloq. Méx. y Perú. Persona callejera.

Por cierto, aunque el diccionario solo menciona el uso de esta expresión coloquial en México y en Perú, en Colombia también es utilizada, aunque coloquialmente aquí solemos suprimir el sonido de la "d" y decir "pata'e perro".

Answer (score 3):

La expresión la he oido en México como "A [nombre de persona] le gusta andar de pata de perro" es decir "A [nombre de persona] le gusta andar siempre afuera".  Con afuera me refiero a cualquier lado distinto al lugar de donde vive.

Answer (score 1):

En Bolivia también se usa 'pata de perro' , sobre todo en la region oriental. Se utiliza como sinónimo de 'callejero', no tanto para quien le gusta viajar.

Answer (score 1):

Y en El Salvador, donde al perro le decimos "chucho", se usa:

> pata de chucho

Vean este [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xyp7xt-ygy0), especialmente de 2:30 a 3:00 minutos.